# mySQL to SQL Migration

Tags: mysql, sql-server, migration

I developed an application using PHP Laravel and MySQL. The database designed is not a good design. So I want to redesign the database in SQL with proper design and planning to do the project in C# ASP.NET. The problem is the developed application has more records in database. How can I achieve this by preserving the records.

Comment: MySQL **is** SQL... Do you mean SQL server? If so, which version?

Comment: yeah, mySQL to SQL Server

Comment: You need to go through a data migration exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are redesigning your database structure there is no magic answer.  However you can do it manually.

1. Design your new system
2. On paper, map fields from one system into another
3. Write a script in any language that extracts the data from your system, transforms it, and loads it into the other system

Congrats!  you have just completed your first major ETL project!

Note there are frameworks to help with this (called ETL frameworks).  Whether they will help you with this is another question.  You may want to look into this but you are more likely to find that your script takes less time to write than learning an ETL framework for a one-time use.